# why the magnetron of Microwave is over heating?

Tags: microwave

I bought GE Spacemaker XL 1800 microwave almost 12 years ago. It was working fine until last week since then it has stopped heating. I searched at the Internet and thought it was the magnetron. I ordered a new magnetron at Amazon and replaced with the previous one. After replacing the magnetron, microwave started to heat normally. In the meantime magnetron was overheating. When I used the microwave consecutively for estimated 10 minutes, microwave cut off. Then I changed Diode and capacitor as well and tried different combinations but the problem didn't go away. It is heating food but magnetron gets overheated and cuts off.

Has anyone faced the similar problem ? Should I replace my microwave or is there any solution ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 12 years is a good life for microwave.

Comment: Some microwaves have more than one thermal fuse in them. If you didn't clean up the grease etc. around the fuse that's tripping, your problem will continue; new magnetron or not.

Answer (score 1):

Microwaves are potentially very dangerous if not repaired correctly. From what you have posted I am concerned you do not have the requisite knowledge to repair it safely. I recommend taking it to a qualified engineer for repair or your local recycling center for safe disposal.